# Parsing date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, string-parsing

Why does the following give an error:

```
    DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
    formatter1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    formatter1.parse("Tue, Nov 26");
```

I don't get why it isn't working.

Comment: What error are you getting? Because it's fine for me... As ZouZou says, perhaps it's because of your system locale?

Comment: @JonSkeet: It was my system locale indeed. Forgot about it. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Next time you ask a question, make sure you provide all the relevant information - if you're getting an exception, tell us what the exception is, etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You're right. Sorry about that. I knew it was something small so I didn't think about supplying more information. Thanks for your criticism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set a `Locale` to your formatter where months are spelt in English, otherwise it's using your default `Locale` :

```
SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)
```

> Constructs a `SimpleDateFormat` using the given pattern and the default
>   date format symbols for the default locale.

I.e :

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d", Locale.US);
```

Comment: That was insanely fast. Worked like a charm. I'll accept when possible. Thanks.